# How to prevent a function from being called from certain sections of code?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I'm implementing a helper class which has a number of useful functions which will be used in a large number of classes. However, a few of them are not designed to be called from within certain sections of code (from interrupt functions, this is an embedded project).

However, for users of this class the reasons why some functions are allowed while others are prohibited from being called from interrupt functions might not be immediately obvious, and in many cases the prohibited functions might work but can cause very subtle and hard to find bugs later on.

The best solution for me would be to cause a compiler error if the offending function is called from a code section it shouldn't be called from.

I've also considered a few non-technical solutions, but a technical one would be preferred.

1. Indicate it in the documentation with a warning. Might be easily missed, especially when the function seems obvious, like `read_byte()`, why would anyone study the documentation whether the function is reentrant or not?
2. Indicate it in the function's name. Ugly. Who likes function names like `read_byte_DO_NOT_CALL_FROM_INTERRUPT()` ?
3. Have a global variable in a common header, included in each and every file, which is set to true at the beginning of each interrupt, set to false at the end, and the offending functions check it at their beginning, and exit if it's set. Problem: interrupts might interrupt each other. Also, it doesn't cause compile-time warnings or errors.
4. Similar to #3, have a global handler with a stack, so that nested interrupts can be handled. Still has the problem of only working at runtime and it also adds a lot of overhead. Interrupts should not waste more than a clock cycle or two for this feature, if at all.
5. Abusing the preprocessor. Unfortunately, the naive way of a `#define` at the beginning and an `#undef` at the end of each interrupt, with an `#ifdef` at the beginning of the offending function doesn't work, because the preprocessor doesn't care about scope.
6. As interrupts are always classless functions, I could make the offending functions `protected`, and declare them as `friends` in all classes which use them. This way, it would be impossible to use them directly from within interrupts. As `main()` is classless, I'll have to place most of it into a class method. I don't like this too much, as it can become needlessly complicated, and the error it generates is not obvious (so users of this function might encapsulate them to "solve" the problem, without realizing what the *real* problem was). A compiler or linker error message like *"ERROR: function_name() is not to be used from within an interrupt"* would be much more preferable.
7. Checking the interrupt registers within the function has several issues. In a large microcontroller there are a lot of registers to check. Also, there is a very small but dangerous chance of a false positive when an interrupt flag is being set exactly one clock cycle before, so my function would fail because it thinks it was called from an interrupt, while the interrupt would be called in the next cycle. Also, in nested interrupts, the interrupt flags are cleared, causing a false negative. And finally, this is yet another runtime solution.

I did play with some very basic template metaprogramming a while ago, but I'm not that experienced with it to find a very simple and elegant solution. I would rather try other ways before committing myself to try to implement a template metaprogramming bloatware.

A solution working with only features available in C would also be acceptable, even preferable.

Comment: It sounds like your interrupt functions are doing too much...

Comment: Don't put the function declarations in the translation units that define the interrupts and treat warnings as errors

Comment: "which will be used in a large number of classes" - makes me think you should put the functions in a base class, and inherit from that base class to bring in the functionality. If this wouldn't work, then what am I missing?

Comment: What exactly differentiates an interrupt function from a "normal" function? And are you in a position where you can decorate all interrupt functions with some code pattern?

Comment: @UKMonkey : Why do you assume that, and why do you think it is relevant? Many such functions are small enough to have their place in interrupts, and what I want to avoid is *future* coders calling one of my functions from an interrupt by mistake.

Comment: @Quentin : I am in a position to decorate them with preprocessor directives. I could theoretically also decorate them with code (like in #3 or #4), but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: "Why do you assume that" I didn't, I said it sounded like it was the case.  "Why do you think it is relevant" Because if your interrupts are kept small and simple then you can't have this problem.

Comment: @UKMonkey : No matter how small, they can cause trouble, depending on what registers those helper functions meddle with.

Comment: Could the downvoters please state their reasons? Such a large number of downvotes in such a little time are usually only observed at completely incomprehensible or blatantly off-topic questions. Do you think it's a case of an XY problem? Please indicate. Do you think the list of suboptimal solutions I wrote is ridiculous? I can gladly remove them. Do you think this question should be asked on another site? Please indicate it with a close vote. Do you think it's a non-issue, or that it has an incredibly obvious solution I totally missed? Then please answer so.

Comment: Why declare all functions in one helper class? Why not have one helper class for functions that may be used in ISRs and another for functions that may not? Then you can declare them in separate headers and include only the former in source files with ISRs. (Also, the latter may be a superset of the former, so non-ISR sources do not need to include both of these headers.) You can additionally provide checks that the non-ISR header is not included in ISR source files.

Comment: Odin Holmes has some great advanced talks about programming c++ in embedded. Here's some ideas : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNXyNa6kf4k

Answer (score 2):

Some comments below. As a warning, they won't be fun reading, but I won't do you a service by not pointing out what's wrong here.

- If you are calling external functions from inside an ISR, no amount of documentation or coding will help you. Since in most cases, it is bad practice to do so. The programmer *must* know what they are doing, or no amount of documentation or coding mechanisms will save the program.

  Programmers do not design library functions specifically for the purpose of getting called from inside an ISR. Rather, programmers design ISR:s with all the special restrictions that come with an ISR in mind: make sure interrupt flags are cleared correctly, keep the code short, do not call external functions, do not block the MCU longer than necessary, consider re-entrancy, consider dangerous compiler optimizations (use volatile). A person who does not know this is not competent enough to write ISRs.
- If you actually have a function `int read_byte(int address)` then this suggests that the program design is bad to begin with. This function could do one of two things:

  - Either it can read a byte some some peripheral hardware, in which case the function name is very bad and should be changed.
  - Or it could read any generic byte from an address, in which case the function is 100% useless "bloatware". You can safely assume that a somewhat competent C programmer can read a byte from a memory address without some bloatware holding their hand.

  In either case, `int` is not a byte. It is a word of 16 or 32 bits. The function should be returning `uint8_t`. Similarly, if the parameter passed is used to descibe a memory-mapped address of an MCU, it should either have type `void*`, `uint8_t*` or `uintptr_t`. Everything else is wrong.

  Notably, if you are using `int` rather than `stdint.h` for embedded systems programming, then this whole discussion is the least of your problems, as you haven't even gotten the fundamental basics right. Your programs will be filled to the brim with undefined behavior and implicit promotion bugs.

Overall, all the solutions you suggest are simply not acceptable. The root of the problem here appears to be the program design. Deal with that instead of inventing ways to defend the broken design with horrible meta programming.

Comment: I am actually using uint8_t for my bytes, that function was just supposed to be a generic example for something which reads from an external I2C memory. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding it caused. And the solutions I suggested were not actually solutions, nor did I suggest them. I actually explained why they aren't good ideas. Why do I sometimes use functions in interrupts? Because in cases I can tolerate the call overhead I would much rather call a function which sets a timer/counter or a serial communications port to a specific state, rather than write 10+ lines of register assignments.

Comment: @vsz In which case you would be using a _local_ function, `inline`:d and not an external one.

Comment: That's true, but that doesn't prevent someone finding one of the functions and calling it from where they shoudln't. Maybe they look into its source, and convince themselves it was safe, but the problem might be very subtle and only detectable after much testing or thinking (and would have nothing to do whether the function is inline or not). This is what I wanted to prevent. Of course, good source comments are a solution, and if someone doesn't read them when they consider using such a function in an interrupt they are to blame, but I wanted to put an extra safety net for convenience.

Comment: @vsz It is really the same situation as when calling a standard library function from inside an ISR. You can't assume anything about how it is implemented, so therefore always expect the worst.

Comment: "use `volatile`". Well, that would be a case where the better advise is "read the manual, understand what your ISR requires, and verify whether `volatile` is both sufficient and necessary". At the root of the problem lies the fact that an ISR happens at assembly level, not at C or C++ level. Processor state is not trivially obvious from the high-level language state.

Comment: @MSalters Everything in a program happens at assembly level... what's your point? I write ISR:s in C all the time, something that I can do because I'm aware of the various dangers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest option 8 & 9.

Peer reviews & assertions.

You state in the comments that your interrupt functions are short.  If that's really the case, then reviewing them will be trivial.  Adding comments in the header will make it so that anyone can see what's going on.  On adding an assert, while you make it viable that debug builds will return the wrong result in error, it will also ensure that you you will catch any calls; and give you a fighting chance during testing to catch the problem.

Ultimately, the macro processing just won't work since the best you can do is catch if a header has been included, but if the callstack goes via another wrapper (that doesn't have comments) then you just can't catch that.

Alternatively you could make your helper a template, but then that would mean every wrapper around your helper would also have to be a template so that can know if you're in an interrupt routine... which will ultimately be your entire code base.

Answer (score 0):

if you have one file for all interrupt routine then this might be helpful:
define one macro in class header ,say FORBID_INTERRUPT_ROUTINE_ACCESS.
and in interrupt handler file check for that macro definition :

```
#ifdef FORBID_INTERRUPT_ROUTINE_ACCESS
#error : cannot access function from interrupt handlers.
#endif
```

if someone add header file for that class to use that class in interrupt handler then it will throw an error.

Note :  you have to build target by specifying that warnings will be considered as error.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the order the headers are included? That doesn't seem ideal...

Comment: @SeanBurton: How would it depend on the order of inclusion? The idea is to put the above `#ifdef` in the source file(s) of ISRs, not in a header. The only order that matters is for the `#ifdef` to be after all header includes. It could be placed at the end of the source file with a comment saying to leave it there and explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C++ template functions suggestion.
I don't think this is metaprogramming or bloatware.

First make 2 classes which will define the context which the user will be using the functions in:

```
class In_Interrupt_Handler;
class In_Non_Interrupt_Handler;
```

If You will have some common implementations between the 2 contexts, a Base class can be added:

```
class Handy_Base
{
 protected:
    static int Handy_protected() { return 0; }
 public:
    static int Handy_public() { return 0; }
};
```

The primary template definition, without any implementations. The implemenations will be provided by the specialization classes:

```
template< class Is_Interrupt_Handler >
class Handy_functions;
```

And the specializations.

```
// Functions can be used when inside an interrupt handler
template<>
struct Handy_functions< In_Interrupt_Handler >
    : Handy_Base
{
    static int Handy1() { return 1; }
    static int Handy2() { return 2; }
};

// Functions can be used when inside any function
template<>
struct Handy_functions< In_Non_Interrupt_Handler > 
    : Handy_Base
{
    static int Handy1() { return 4; }
    static int Handy2() { return 8; }
};
```

In this way if the user of the API wants to access the functions, the only way is by specifing what type of functions are needed.

Example of usage:

```
int main()
{
    using IH_funcs = Handy_functions<In_Interrupt_Handler>;
    std::cout << IH_funcs::Handy1() << '\n';
    std::cout << IH_funcs::Handy2() << '\n';

    using Non_IH_funcs = Handy_functions<In_Non_Interrupt_Handler>;
    std::cout << Non_IH_funcs::Handy1() << '\n';
    std::cout << Non_IH_funcs::Handy2() << '\n';

}
```

In the end I think the problem boils down to the developer using Your framework. And How much Your framework requires the devloper to boilerplate.

The above does not stop the developer calling the Non Interrupt Handler functions from inside an Interrupt Handler.

I think that type of analysis would require some type of static analysis checking system.